# How to change position of parent anchor in root node in forest environment?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I have this code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\forestset{% this specifies a style, direction switch, which manages the layout, formatting and tweaking of the various levels and nodes of the tree itself
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={l sep=-10em,
      draw=DodgerBlue2,
      thick,
      inner ysep=2pt,
      edge={thick},
      if level=1{% the root node is level 0 so this is the layer of horizontally aligned nodes beneath it
        parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-.5em) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        for descendants={% apply to everything beneath level 1
          child anchor=west,
          align=left,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
          s sep+=1.5pt,
          fit=band,
        },
        for tree={% apply to everything in level 1 or beneath level 1
          parent anchor=south west,
          anchor=mid west,
          grow'=0,
          font=\sffamily,
          if n children=0{}{
            delay={
              prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
            }
          },
          before computing xy={
            l=2em
          }
        },
      }{
        if level=0{% this is the root node of the tree, level 0
          parent anchor=south,
          anchor=south,
          before drawing tree={% we repack just the top bit of the tree, right at the end, to account for the increased spacing introduced by moving things around; after repacking, we need to explicitly recompute the x-y coordinates as well, before the tree is drawn
            pack',
            compute xy,
          }
        }{},
      },
    },
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
  direction switch% apply the style defined above
  % specify the content of the tree
  [{Dry Air Oxidation (\ch{U + O2})}
    [Chemical Diffusion
      [Quasi-steady diffusion
        [Comparison with GK model
        ]
      ]
      [Unsteady diffusion
        [Neglecting volumetric changes
            [Numerical  + Analytical\\ + Asymptotics]
        ]
        [Including volumetric changes
            [Numerical solution]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Ionic Diffusion
      [Moderate Electric Field
        [Quasi-steady diffusion]
        [Unsteady diffusion]
      ]
      [Strong Electric Field
        [Quasi-steady]
        [Unsteady diffusion]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image: this document]. I would like to to be able to change the position of the anchor from the root node; in other words to center 'Dry Air Oxidation'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with an approximate solution, you could just add `parent anchor=-160`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\forestset{% this specifies a style, direction switch, which manages the layout, formatting and tweaking of the various levels and nodes of the tree itself
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={l sep=-10em,
      draw=DodgerBlue2,
      thick,
      inner ysep=2pt,
      edge={thick},
      if level=1{% the root node is level 0 so this is the layer of horizontally aligned nodes beneath it
        parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-.5em) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        for descendants={% apply to everything beneath level 1
          child anchor=west,
          align=left,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
          s sep+=1.5pt,
          fit=band,
        },
        for tree={% apply to everything in level 1 or beneath level 1
          parent anchor=south west,
          anchor=mid west,
          grow'=0,
          font=\sffamily,
          if n children=0{}{
            delay={
              prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
            }
          },
          before computing xy={
            l=2em
          }
        },
      }{
        if level=0{% this is the root node of the tree, level 0
          parent anchor=south,
          anchor=south,
          before drawing tree={% we repack just the top bit of the tree, right at the end, to account for the increased spacing introduced by moving things around; after repacking, we need to explicitly recompute the x-y coordinates as well, before the tree is drawn
            pack',
            compute xy,
          }
        }{},
      },
    },
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
  direction switch% apply the style defined above
  % specify the content of the tree
  [{Dry Air Oxidation (\ch{U + O2})},parent anchor=-160
    [Chemical Diffusion
      [Quasi-steady diffusion
        [Comparison with GK model
        ]
      ]
      [Unsteady diffusion
        [Neglecting volumetric changes
            [Numerical  + Analytical\\ + Asymptotics]
        ]
        [Including volumetric changes
            [Numerical solution]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Ionic Diffusion
      [Moderate Electric Field
        [Quasi-steady diffusion]
        [Unsteady diffusion]
      ]
      [Strong Electric Field
        [Quasi-steady]
        [Unsteady diffusion]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also compute the node anchor. This is achieved by using `([xshift={2pt+0.5*width("Dry Air Oxidation")}]!u.south west)` instead of `(!u.parent anchor)` in the `level=1` case.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\forestset{% this specifies a style, direction switch, which manages the layout, formatting and tweaking of the various levels and nodes of the tree itself
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={l sep=-10em,
      draw=DodgerBlue2,
      thick,
      inner ysep=2pt,
      edge={thick},
      if level=1{% the root node is level 0 so this is the layer of horizontally aligned nodes beneath it
        parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] 
          ([xshift={2pt+0.5*width("Dry Air Oxidation")}]!u.south west) -- ++(0,-.5em) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        for descendants={% apply to everything beneath level 1
          child anchor=west,
          align=left,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
          s sep+=1.5pt,
          fit=band,
        },
        for tree={% apply to everything in level 1 or beneath level 1
          parent anchor=south west,
          anchor=mid west,
          grow'=0,
          font=\sffamily,
          if n children=0{}{
            delay={
              prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
            }
          },
          before computing xy={
            l=2em
          }
        },
      }{
        if level=0{% this is the root node of the tree, level 0
          parent anchor=south,
          anchor=south,
          before drawing tree={% we repack just the top bit of the tree, right at the end, to account for the increased spacing introduced by moving things around; after repacking, we need to explicitly recompute the x-y coordinates as well, before the tree is drawn
            pack',
            compute xy,
          }
        }{},
      },
    },
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
  direction switch% apply the style defined above
  % specify the content of the tree
  [{Dry Air Oxidation (\ch{U + O2})}
    [Chemical Diffusion
      [Quasi-steady diffusion
        [Comparison with GK model
        ]
      ]
      [Unsteady diffusion
        [Neglecting volumetric changes
            [Numerical  + Analytical\\ + Asymptotics]
        ]
        [Including volumetric changes
            [Numerical solution]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Ionic Diffusion
      [Moderate Electric Field
        [Quasi-steady diffusion]
        [Unsteady diffusion]
      ]
      [Strong Electric Field
        [Quasi-steady]
        [Unsteady diffusion]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A tree}
\centering
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={rounded corners,draw,fill=gray!20,font=\sffamily,
    align=left,text width=7em,s sep+=0.5em}
[\textbf{Approach}
 [{\textbf{location-based}\\[1.2em] blub}]
 [{\textbf{inertia-based}\\[1.2em] blah}]
 [{\textbf{hybrid}\\[1.2em] pft}]
]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understood, the OP wants to center the top blue rectangle with respect to the first black horizontal line.

Comment: @sigur Thanks! Maybe you are right. However, I thought "change the position of the anchor from the root node; in other words to center 'Dry Air Oxidation'. " means that the anchor gets moved to the center of 'Dry Air Oxidation', which this answer does.

Comment: Yes, I would like to center the top blue rectangle w.r.t the first black horizontal line as Sigur says. Sorry if it's worded wrongly.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I don't see difference between your blue rect. and OP's one. Both looks with centered black connector.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, my English is not good but do you know how I supposed that? Because it would be prettier to the eyes!!! lol

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks. I used 'xshift' for level=0, and it works.

Comment: @mnatch Yes, you need `xshift=-5em`.